# Advertencia en Octave Plot: Broken pipe -- some output may be lost

Tags: octave, gnuplot

Estoy intentando plotear en *Octave 3.4.0* y aunque tengo GNUplot me sale la siguiente advertencia:

> octave-3.4.0:6> sombrero
>   warning: broken pipe -- some output may be lost
>   warning: broken pipe -- some output may be lost
>   warning: broken pipe -- some output may be lost
>   ...

¿Qué debo hacer en estos casos?